# How to forbid the movement between 2 UITableViewCells in different section in same UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 2 sections.
The UITableCells in the same section can be moved.
But I hope to forbid the movement between 2 UITableViewCells in different sections of a same UITableView.
Is it possible?

Welcome any commnet

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

```
if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == sourceIndexPath.section)
    return sourceIndexPath;
```

This will cause the row to go back to it's source indexpath if the section that it's trying to move to, isn't the same section as it's original indexpath